# Optimize MySQL query with larger database

Tags: mysql, select, optimization, bulkinsert

how can be write the below query efficiently

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id 
FROM table1 a where a.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT b.id 
                                 FROM table2 b)
```

Post this query the result is inserted into table2 via an insert query.

The problem is that table1 has approx ~75300 records and table2 has ~74000 records.

This query is to be executed every 10 mins and it takes approx 1.5 mins to execute.

Any possibilities this query could be faster?

Comment: don't use sub-query and your query will be faster.

Comment: Do you suggest using joins?

Comment: Yes. Why not using JOIN ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a `Join`

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id from table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b
on a.id = b.id
Where b.id is null
```

The `Left Join` clause will select all rows from `a` regardless of whether or not there are matching rows in `b`. You then can use the `where` clause at the end to ensure that the rows returned from `a` have no match in `b`

Comment: The query returns no results! this could be because with the join the records with common ids will be filtered and the where condition filters the ids that are not common which is contradictory.

Comment: @gunjansoni2002 see my latest update. That will return *all* records from `a` only where the `id` didn't equal the `id` in b